# Android WebView UrlReferrer is always null ASP .net

Tags: android, asp.net, webview, null, referrer

I'm sorry that my English is poor.
In Android WebView, UrlReferrer is always null.
But same webpage UrlReferrer is not null in mobile web browser.
Web application is ASP.net.
plz, save my life.

my WebView Setting

```
    WebSettings settings = wvContent.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    settings.setSupportZoom(true);
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true); 
    settings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
    settings.setTextZoom(100);
    settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```

And, can I print the UrlReferrer value to the logcat?

Comment: Are you trying to display a asp.net web application link in android app ?

Comment: Thanks for comment. I tried to attach load url to button, but it was the same.